# How to add a values dynamically using selenium/python

Tags: excel, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Please find the details below

What I want to do

I have to open a webpage and go to a tab.in the tab I have n number of link it may contain one link or five link there are randomly present.when I open the first link I have only one value present.similarly on opening other link I will have only one value.now I have add all the values present each link and write in an Excel. For example:first link has 2, second link has 3.i wand add the two values (2+3=5) and store it

What I have done so far.

I am iterating based on the number of links present in the tab.the code run untill all the link present in tab has run through.it will open the first link ,take the value and am storing the value as float (sheetnew.write(1,6,float(Storedvalue)) )so that I could take the value as number and add it to the next value present in the next link.When I am running the code,I will check if that particular cell is empy by (if textcomment ==none).if cell is empty it will store the value of the first link as float in the cell(1,6).then it will open the second link,it will check if the cell is empty.since it will not empty ,it will contain the value of first link.so it will run the else part where I am getting the value of the first link from Excel as (textcomment=details.cell(1,6))and the new value from second link as(Storedvalue=Commentvalue.text).now I am trying to add the two values

issue I am facing:

So I not able to add the value together.i tried to add by (Addedvalue= float (textcomment.value) + float(Storedvalue)).but I not able to do it.i am have the below error

```
button=driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[@class="btn btn-small btn-success pull-right"]/span[@class="text"]');
       button.click();
       time.sleep(10);
       textcomment=details.cell(1,6)
       if textcomment == None:
        Commentvalue=driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[2]/div/ul/li[2]/a/span')
        Storedvalue=Commentvalue.text;
        sheetnew.write(1,6,float(Storedvalue));
        wb.save('excel path');
        driver.close();
        driver.switch_to.window(window_before);
       else:
            textcomment=details.cell(1,6)
            Commentvalue=driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[2]/div/ul/li[2]/a/span')
            Storedvalue=Commentvalue.text;
            Addedvalue= float (textcomment.value) + float(Storedvalue);
            sheetnew.write(1,6,float(Addedvalue));
            wb.save('excel path');
            driver.close();
            driver.switch_to.window(window_before);
```

Error

```
Addedvalue= float (textcomment.value) + float(Storedvalue);

ValueError: could not convert string to float:
```

If there is any other way to achieve this please let me know.

Comment: `ValueError: could not convert string to float: `. One of your values is a string which cannot be converted. Work out where the invalid float data is in the string.

Comment: what are the value for `textcomment.value` and `Storedvalue`?

Comment: @supputuri:Those values  differes based on link .let say the first link has 5,i will take the value as num=value .text and store it as float(num).

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are passing string with only numbers, when you are using float.

[image]

Comment: If that does not work then please share the complete error message.